# PHP script runs on command line, but not in browser

Tags: php, mysql, apache2

I'm a complete beginner at this, but I've set up an EC2 server and I'm trying to develop a simple php-mysql based website.

I've managed to get apache2 running and I've got a domain pointed to the server. I'm trying to set up a very simple php script to attach to a database. The following script runs perfectly well when I use the command line `php simple_script.php`

```
<?php

echo "Hello\n";

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","james","<password>");
if($con){
echo "Connected\n";
}
?>
```

However, when I go to `www.myurl.com/simple_script.php` I only see the line "Hello". Any help would be gratefully received!

OK, so I've checked the apache error log, which is saying this:
`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/www.myurl.com/simple_script.php on line 5`
Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: What does the EC2's error log tell?

Comment: PHP via command line and via web browser may have different configurations, so maybe the extension mysql is not loaded for php web

Comment: Use mysqli/pdo - php_mysql is now officially deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a deprecated function.  Use mysqli_* or look into the PDO class.  http://php.net has a great documentation on the language :)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried changing the call to use mysqli_connect instead, it still works in the command line but not on the web! I'm thinking it must be a server configuration problem!

Comment: Try [ if (!$con) ] to be sure your not connected?

Comment: It worked after I restarted Apache, which seems a bit strange, I should probably have tried that sooner, cheers.

Comment: Ive actually had that issue before.

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
else {
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

To figure out the error

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to figure things out (and if this isn't on a production server), I'd start by displaying php errors by enabling error reporting in your php.ini file.  To find out where php.ini is located, create a file that uses the phpinfo() function, and you should get the path. (This will also show you if mysql is running.)

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

In php.ini, look for the "error_reporting" line and set it to something like:

error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE